# Adding a remote node in Rundeck 3

Tags: rundeck

I'm trying out rundeck (3.0.13) for the first time.  I've followed the instructions in this web page: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-add-remote-nodes-to-rundeck/, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to create a remote node.  In brief, the steps are

- Add a key to key storage that has the username/password for the remote node.  (I left the default storage path as "keys")
- Create a project, change the ssh/scp parameters to use password au8thentication using that username/pass combo
- Create a file called resources.xml in the project /etc folder, and specify the remote node in there.
- Restart rundeck
- Wait a few minutes and the node should be visible on the nodes page of the project

  Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  All I see is the default local server node.  (I used the "Select All Nodes" feature, so it's not a filter problem.)

  I don't see any errors in the logs;  I verified that I can log into the remote node from the rundeck server node using ssh and the credentials I provided.  My remote node has an IP address, but as this is a test, I didn't make a DNS entry for it.  Is there anything else I can try or look at for diagnostic information?  I'm not even sure it's hitting the resources.xml file.

**UPDATE**

I was able to get this working by using the GUI to load the resources.xml file after project creation.

In the tutorial, the author puts this file into the /etc of the project and rundeck just finds it.  If instead, the same resources.xml file is specified as a "File" source of nodes, it loads.

Ironically not seeing any errors in the logs was the biggest clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue that I resolved as follow:

1. Add a file named `resources.xml` in the project folder / etc folder. (if it's not there, create one). It should have the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project>
  <node name="somename" description="Rundeck 1" tags="" hostname="xx.xx.xx.xx" osArch="amd64" osFamily="unix" osName="Linux" osVersion="3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64" username="xyz"/>
</project>
```

2. go to project setings via `UI --> edit nodes`
3. Add a source from type 'File'.

   - format: select the resourcexml.
   - file path: use pwd and get the path, it should also include the /resources.xml file name at the end, like `/home/xxx/rundeck/projects/test/etc/resources.xml`
4. select generate
5. save and restart the rundeck